# In Excel, calculate sum of a column where multiple cells contain specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, automation

I have a large dataset I'm working with consisting of many records that represent lines on a map. The order heirarchy is State -> County -> Line # -> Line Class -> Line Length. There are multiple classes in each line, and some lines span multiple counties. Here is what the dataset looks like:

[image: Dataset_Sample]

I need to calculate the length of records in each class, on each line, in each county, in each state. There are thousands of records so automation is the best route to take. The resulting table needs to be in this format:

[image: Summary_Table]

Perhaps I'm overthinking this but I have not yet found a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: Came here to say that ^. Leaving satisfied. That's exactly what a Pivot Table does for you.

Comment: Wow, I am really kicking myself for not learning pivot tables before now. That was EXACTLY what I needed and was surprisingly intuitive to figure out. Thanks!

Comment: @Duderino, Y don't you think for Group & Subtotal. Group on Class and get the Sum of Length Column. You get what you are looking for !